# Component not returning UI even though props are being delivered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fairly new to React so I think the problem here is likely to be pretty basic. I'm displaying a list of regions and when a user clicks on a region I am passing an object via props to a CountryList component:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SelectRegion 
                    selectedRegion={this.state.selectedRegion} 
                    onSelect={this.updateBoth} />
                { !this.state.countryCodes
                    ? "Select a region"
                    : <CountryList countryCodes={this.state.countryCodes} /> }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

The SelectRegion component works fine, but the CountryList is only rendering the component without content. Here is the CountryList component.

```
function CountryList(props) {
    return (
        <ul className="country-list">
            {Object.entries(props.countryCodes).forEach(([key, val]) => {
                return (
                    <li 
                        key={key}
                        className="country-item" >
                            <div className="country-code">{key}</div>
                            <ul className="space-list-items">
                                <li>
                                    <img
                                        className="flag"
                                        src={`http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/flag/${key}.png`}
                                        alt={"Flag for " + val}
                                    />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
                )
            })}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

If I look in the inspector, I can see that when the user clicks on the region the state is updated, the CountryList component is added to the page (as well as the `<ul></ul>`) and that it has the appropriate props (an object). What am I missing that's keeping the component from displaying?

If it's helpful, this is the entire component:

```js
function App () {
 return (
   <div>
    <Selector />
   </div>  
 )
}

function SelectRegion (props) {
 const regionCountry = {
  "Europe": {
   "PL": "Poland",
   "HU": "Hungary",
   "DE": "Germany",
   "AT": "Austria",
   "DK": "Denmark", 
   "ES": "Spain", 
   "GR": "Greece",
   "IT": "Italy",
   "CH": "Switzerland",
   "RU": "Russia",
   "FR": "France",
   "BE": "Belgium",
   "LU": "Luxembourg",
   "SE": "Sweden",
   "NO": "Norway",
   "SI": "Slovenia",
   "LT": "Lithuania",
   "CY": "Cyprus",
   "LV": "Latvia",
   "BG": "Bulgaria",
   "HR": "Croatia",
   "GB": "United Kingdom",
   "IE": "Ireland",
   "GE": "Georgia",
   "RO": "Romania",
   "FI": "Finland",
   "NL": "Netherlands",
   "ME": "Montenegro"

  },
  "Americas": {
   "CA": "Canada",
   "US": "USA",
   "MX": "Mexico",
   "BR": "Brazil",
   "CL": "Chile",
   "AR": "Argentina",
   "CO": "Columbia",
   "UY": "Uruguay"
  },
  "APAC": {
   "AU": "Australia",
   "NZ": "New Zealand",
   "KZ": "Kazakhstan",
   "JP": "Japan",
   "TH": "Thailand",
   "TW": "Taiwan"
  },
  "Middle East & Africa": {
   "IL": "Israel",
   "TR": "Turkey",
   "AE": "UAE",
   "SA": "South Africa"
  }
 }

 return (
  <ul className="regions">
   {Object.keys(regionCountry).map((region) => {
    return(
     <li
     style={region === props.selectedRegion ? {color: '#d0021b'} : null}
     onClick={props.onSelect.bind(null, region, regionCountry[region])}
              key={region} >
               {region}
              </li>
             )
   })}
        </ul>
 )
}

function CountryList(props) {
 return (
  <ul className="country-list">
   {Object.entries(props.countryCodes).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    return (
     <li 
      key={key}
      className="country-item" >
       <div className="country-code">{key}</div>
       <ul className="space-list-items">
        <li>
         <img
          className="flag"
          src={"http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/flag/"+key+".png"}
          alt={"Flag for " + val}
         />
        </li>
       </ul>
     </li>
    )
   })}
  </ul>
 )
}

class Selector extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
   selectedRegion: null,
   countryCodes: null
  }

  this.updateRegion = this.updateRegion.bind(this);
  this.updateCountries = this.updateCountries.bind(this);
  this.updateBoth = this.updateBoth.bind(this);
 }

 updateRegion(region) { selectedRegion: region }

 updateCountries(countries) { countryCodes: countries }

 updateBoth(updateRegion, updateCountries) {
  this.setState(() => {
   return {
    selectedRegion: updateRegion,
    countryCodes: updateCountries
   }
  })
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <div>
    <SelectRegion 
     selectedRegion={this.state.selectedRegion} 
     onSelect={this.updateBoth} />
    { !this.state.countryCodes
     ? "Select a region"
     : <CountryList countryCodes={this.state.countryCodes} /> }
   </div>
  )
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <App />,
 document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Oxygen-Sans,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #d0021b;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.button {
  color: #e6e6e6;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 7px 0;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.button:hover:enabled {
  background: linear-gradient(#1a1a1a,#0a0a0a);
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button:active {
  transform: translateY(1px);
}

.regions {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.regions li {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.country-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.country-item {
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.country-code {
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello Express</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using some transpiler option that makes `updateRegion(region) { selectedRegion: region }` meaningful? I haven't seen any proposals for anything like that. Absent some proposal that makes it meaningful, that's a functon that doesn't do anything. It defines a labelled statement which is just an *ExpressionStatement* of the `region` value.

Comment: It's also not clear where `updateBoth` is meant to magically get its arguments from.

Comment: No transpiler, was just hacking at it to try to get it to return the correct values for the state. To be honest, I'm also at a bit of a loss. Countries was an old variable from an earlier attempt that got left there. Somehow though it returns the correct value, here's my inspector view http://imgur.com/a/8G5AQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty `<ul></ul>` must mean that the `props.countryCodes` is not set, the loop for Object.entries looks good to me. The problem looks like your callback 'updateBoth' is to blame, `onSelect={this.updateBoth}` passes no parameters to `updateBoth(updateRegion, updateCountries)` so your state cannot set any value for countryCodes.

**Edit**

I can make your code work with:

```
function CountryList(props) {
    console.log(props);
    return (
        <ul className="country-list">
            {
                Object.keys(props.countryCodes).map((key) => {
                    console.log(key);
                    return (
                        <li
                            key={ key }
                            className="country-item" >
                            <div className="country-code">{key}</div>
                            <ul className="space-list-items">
                                <li>
                                    <img
                                        className="flag"
                                        src={"http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/flag/"+key+".png"}
                                        alt={"Flag for " + props.countryCodes[key]}
                                    />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    );
                })

            }
        </ul>
    )
}
```

Comment: If I check the state of `<Selector />` in the React inspector after I click on a region I see the state set as: `countryCodes: {object that has country codes and names} selectRegion: "string of whatever was clicked on"`

Comment: Interesting, I don't see how that happens, perhaps I'm blind. Anyway, i'll edit this so it works for you

Comment: This works, thank you so much! If I look at the code changes, it looks like the problem is in the way `entries` is written, right?

Comment: I think the problem is more that forEach doesn't return an array of jsx that map does.